# saving the path of the picture in MYSQL database using visual basic 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I try to save the "path" on MYSQL database but I get the error
`the datatype of photo is BLOB`
database is imageupload
table is student
hope someone can help me to fix my error and order to save the path on database
thanks a lot more power to us!!!

My error is that
`"The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context."`

My connection in module

```
Module Module1
    Public cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Sub konek()
        With cn
            .ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MY SQL ODBC 5.1 driver};SERVER=localhost;PWD=;UID=root;database=imageupload"
        End With
    End Sub
End Module
```

======================================================================
My form in Visual Basic 2010

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnbrowsepic_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnbrowsepic.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""

        With OpenFileDialog1
            .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
            .Filter = "All Files|*.*|Bitmaps|*.bmp|GIFs|*.gif|JPEGs|*.jpg"
            .FilterIndex = 2
        End With

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            With PictureBox1
                .Image = Image.FromFile(Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            End With
        End If
        Me.lblpath.Text = Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnsavepic_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsavepic.Click
        rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.Open("select * from student", cn, 3, 3)----- error is here when i save the path on my database
        With rs
            .AddNew()
            .Fields("photo").Value = "" & lblpath.Text
            .Update()
            MsgBox("Data has been saved")
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You'll need to show us your actual code please. And are you using VB.NET?

Comment: yes visual basic 2010

Comment: You talk about two error messages "The datatype of the photo is Blob" and "The connection cannot be used to perform this operation." Can you tell us where each of those errors happens?

Comment: only one error only sir. it only happens when i save the path of the picture on my database... i only describe that the data type of the photo on my sql database is blob..

Comment: Where does konek() get called? And where is it opened? Have a look at this for the basic setup: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315974

Comment: on the form load of my form sir

Comment: And where are you calling cn.Open()? I think it would be worth trying to move all the connection setup and open code into the btnsavepic_Click method so all your db code is in one place and see if it works like that first. And there's no need to call people sir here :)